# Ignore errors in Insert from select statement SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way or a command to ignore duplicated primary key error when inserting data from a select?

**Explanation**
Lets suppose i have this query: `Insert into my_table values (select * from my_second_table)` but `my_table` has a primary key on `id`. Also `my_second_table` has a column named `id` so when attempting the insert it cause a duplicated primary key error.

I know i can avoid these kind of problems using `go` but in this case i cant use it because is an insert from a select, or at least is what i know.

Is there something i can do?

Comment: Use merge statement in this case

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If Sql server you can look at `ignore_dup_key = on`

Comment: @MartinSmith im using MsSql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different databases have different methods for conflict resolution.  The following works in most databases:

```
Insert into my_table values ( . . . )  -- you should always list all the columns
     select . . .   -- you should list all the columns
     from my_second_table t2
     where not exists (select 1 from my_table t where t.id = t2.id);
```

This is not a perfect solution, because race conditions could cause problems.  But it will work if no other data modification queries run on the server while this is being executed.

Comment: Nice, i thought about doing something like that. The problem is that consumes too much time and resources to perform the action but I'm gonna give it a try.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz . . . You just need an index on `my_table(id)`.

Comment: Actually i just used id as an example. My real primary key is a clustered key of 5 columns and there is already an index and some clustered indexes on the table

Comment: Well, i tried and it work. Thanks. It is just a little bit slower but i doesn't matter for now, lets see in a couple of months. I end up using left join instead of a sub-query